# Code Required to achieve vertical slider effect in Wordpress (examples included)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm wondering how I can achieve an effect similar to that of http://eng.getlost-getnatural.ru/ or http://rnbtheme.com/sixteenth/. I've contacted various support forums supplied through Wordpress and all they've been able to tell me is that I need to get a web developer and that the effect was possible. I, however, don't have the money for a web developer and went searching online to try to find what I was looking for and haven't been able to find anything yet. I can make code changes to my Wordpress site using javascript or css. Thank you so much to everyone who helps and answers!

Comment: So what are your expectations here.... a free developer? This isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for could take a couple of hours to code from scratch, and then trying to match it to a wordpress site that we can't see or use as reference can create a lot of problems. I recommend looking at some jQuery plugins.

Here is a site to get you started, https://www.jssor.com/demos/vertical-slider.slider.

If you have any questions about the code once you download the plugin then we will be able to help you further.